# Removing specific emacs x resources

Tags: x11

I have some `X Resources` associated with `EMACS`. I want to remove those EMACS resources? How can I use `xrdb -remove`? Have not found much information and even less examples on what to do?

```
xrdb -query -all | grep -i emacs

Emacs*Background:   #000000
Emacs*Dialog*background:    #000000
Emacs*Dialog*foreground:    #ffffff
Emacs*Foreground:   #ffffff
Emacs*XlwScrollBar.Background:  #000000
Emacs*XlwScrollBar.Foreground:  #ffffff
Emacs*backgroundToolBarColor:   #000000
Emacs*bottomToolBarShadowColor: #000000
Emacs*menubar*background:   #000000
Emacs*menubar*foreground:   #ffffff
Emacs*popup*Background: #000000
Emacs*popup*Foreground: #ffffff
Emacs*topToolBarShadowColor:    #000000
Emacs.default.attributeBackground:  #000000
Emacs.default.attributeForeground:  #ffffff
Emacs.mode-line.attributeForeground:    #ffffff
Emacs.scroll-bar.attributeBackground:   #000000
Emacs.scroll-bar.attributeForeground:   #ffffff
Emacs.tool-bar.attributeBackground: #000000
Emacs.tool-bar.attributeForeground: #ffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe xrdb persists resources across invocations as a native capability, so they should reset when you log out and log back in, or if you kill xrdb and restart it.

If they keep coming back across login sessions, they're probably being loaded from your shell init scripts somewhere. They're typically read via something like `xrdb -load $HOME/.Xresources` but that is only convention.

Search your personal and the shared rc scripts for your shell on the system and search your home directory for files that contain resource definitions.

Comment: I do not wish to log out.  Would killing xrdb and restarting it, affect the system beyond emacs?

Comment: I do not have the file `$HOME/.Xresources`.

Answer (score 0):

[`xrdb`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrdb.1.html) (see [source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrdb/-/blob/master/xrdb.c#L1269)) removes all of the X server data for what it terms `SCREEN_RESOURCES` or `XA_RESOURCE_MANAGER`.  You're only interested in the latter.  Removing that will do more than what you probably intended, so you'd have to use `xrdb -q` to get the current data, edit that, and reload it.

That's not necessarily simple, because resources can have continuation-lines.  Your example doesn't do that.  Limiting it to that (I don't think it's likely that you have configured **screen** resources, so the `-all` option is unnecessary):

```
xrdb -q | grep -v -i emacs > foo
xrdb -load foo
```

Referring to the manpage would be helpful...

Killing/restarting `xrdb` will have no effect on the X server data.

Not mentioned in the manpage (which needs some work), `xrdb` accepts abbreviations for all of its options, e.g. the [`-query` option](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrdb/-/blob/master/xrdb.c#L987) can be given as just `-q`:

```c
            else if (isabbreviation("-query", arg, 2)) {
                oper = OPQUERY;
                continue;
            }
```

That `2` is the length of **`-q`**.  Incidentally, its code for **`-quiet`** allows the same length, but since that is tested **after** `-query`, you would have to abbreviate that as **`-qui`**.

Comment: I do not see the `-q` option.

Comment: Looks like `internal-set-lisp-face-attribute-from-resource` is doing the work.  My position is that Emacs should test whether it is using an init file.  If there is no init file, why load xrdb settings?

Comment: You have not explained precisely how to use `xrdb -q` to get the current data, edit it, and reload it.